# Reset the table Auto Increment and make it apply to the table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with around 10k rows which I've imported. The ID is a significant column to my application, and it has to be ordered. Currently, I got something like: 1,2,3,4,5....5789,9275,9276.....

It jumped from 5789 to 9275. Is there any way I can reset the Auto Increment but also make it apply to the table? which means, now it will start giving them IDS all over again from 1 to 10k

Thanks!

Comment: Delete the column and recreate it,it that's an option,after resetting autoincrement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> AUTO_INCREMENT=<new_value>;
```

Of course you need to fix the high IDs and all references to them manually.

However, why do you care? Does it really matter if there's a hole in the IDs? If yes, you might want to use a *separate column* that's always set to `MAX(col) + 1` instead of an AUTO_INCREMENT column.

Comment: You have to. Especially if there are references to those IDs. Changing IDs is usually a bad idea for exactly that reason.

Comment: @kfirba, you can write a script to reindex the id values if you wanted.  more work, but it's what you want right?

Comment: @SlyRaskal Theif has mentioned calling the setting the ID column to be `MAX(col) + 1` instead of Auto Increment. what is `col`? I would like to give it a try

Comment: `col` is just a placeholder for whatever column name you decide to go with if you follow his plan.

Comment: Since you tagged this post with phpMyAdmin, note that you can do this graphically from the Operations tab of the table. ThiefMaster has the right answer, of course, but phpMyAdmin makes it pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly reset the auto_increment value to be whatever you want by simply issuing this query:

```
ALTER TABLE <tbl> AUTO_INCREMENT = <n>;
```

where tbl is your table name and n is the value to start it at.  However, if you have existing IDs in that table already, I believe it will simply set the next inserted items ID to be `max(id) + 1` of the ID column

Comment: whats `id`? If I don't have the column ID, I can just specify and other column?

Comment: 'id` was just a loose term for whatever column name your table has set for the auto_increment column.  Sorry, I should have been more clear.